# How do you copy files from a Salt master and execute them on a Salt minion?

Tags: salt-stack

I want to copy a directory from my Salt master to my Salt Minion. All the files are executable. I want to then execute the files on my Salt minion.

I want to achieve this using a Salt state. This is what I have so far:

```
copy_scripts:
  file.recurse:
    - name: /root/scripts
    - source: salt://files/scripts
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - file_mode: 744
```

This puts the files on my Salt minion. How can I execute all the scripts inside?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with cmd.script. cmd.script will copy the file (script?) to the minion and run it in a single state.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.script

You'd need a state for every script you wanted to run.

bonus points: You can use Jinja to loop through a list to generate the states automatically https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt3.html

Comment: I have a directory in which files are stored which needs to be executed. How can I run all those files using cmd.scripts, I don't want to hardcode the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the directory to the desired path, you can use [cmd.run](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run) to execute these scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't want to hardcode the name of the files inside for loop to execute the files

Comment: then you can make a list of these script using https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.find through jinja then execute the list of these scripts and in this case there is no hard coded data